# How to get on a Category Page the subcategory and posts?

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, posts

I would know how I can get on a Wordpress Category Page (category.php) the subcategory and the posts of this subcategory?

I have now this code below, and there where the "`echo 'test';`" ist I want to show the posts of the parent category.

```
<?php
$args = array('child_of' => get_query_var('cat') );
$categories = get_categories( $args );

$numOfItems = 20; // Set no of category per page
$page = isset( $_GET['cpage'] ) ? abs( (int) $_GET['cpage'] ) : 1;
$to = $page * $numOfItems;
$current = $to - $numOfItems;
$total = sizeof( $categories );

echo '<ul class="cat-content">';
for( $i=$current; $i<$to; ++$i ) {
    $category = $categories[$i];
    if( $category->name ) {
        echo '<li><h2>'. $category->name.'</h2>';

        echo 'test';

        echo '</li>';
    }
}
echo '</ul>';

unset( $category );

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place this where `echo "test";` is.

```
// The Query
$args = array('post_type' => post, 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'cat' => $category->term_id );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'" >' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    // no posts found
}
```

Comment: Hi @WordpressDave

Thanks a lot. It worked for me. I need also to get the Post Links. Now i have only the title. How can i get also the links?